# Convergence in Disjoint Union Topoloy

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Let $X=\mathbb{R}\sqcup \mathbb{R}$ with its disjoin union topology.  Then does a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converge in $X$ if and only if there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

- $\{x_n\}_{n\geq N}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and
- $\{x_n\}_{n \geq N}$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$ for its Euclidean topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $X=\mathbb{R}_0\cup \mathbb{R}_1$ to distinguish both copies.

Suppose $x_n\to x$ in $X$. WLOG, $x\in\mathbb{R}_0$. As $\mathbb{R}_0$ is an open nbhd of $x$ in $X$, it follows that there is some $N$ with $x_n\in \mathbb{R}_0$ for all $n\ge N$. Now use that, if $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, then $U$ can be viewed as an open nbhd of $x$ in $X$.

For the converse, if $U$ is a nbhd of $x$ (the limit of $\{x_n\}_{n\ge N}$ in $\mathbb{R}$) in $X$, then $U\cap \mathbb{R}$ is a nbhd of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$. But then $x_n\in U\cap \mathbb{R}$ for all sufficiently large $n\ge N$.

Comment: Is it possibly to use $X$ to describe pairs of elements $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}_0\cup\mathbb{R}_1$ with convergence only possibly if $x_1$ converges in $\mathbb{R}_0$ and $x_2$ converges in $\mathbb{R}_1$, eventually?

Comment: @James_T The disjoint union should not be thought of as a set of pairs of real numbers. Rather, you have two copies of $\mathbb{R}$ which you regard as two halves of a space. You might be thinking of $\mathbb{R}_0\times\mathbb{R}_1$.

Comment: I guess I am thinking of the set $\mathbb{R}_0\times \mathbb{R}_1$ but can it be topologized such that it is characterized by the above form of convergence?

Comment: @James_T Yes. If $\mathbb{R}_0\times\mathbb{R}_1$ is given the product topology, a sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ converges (in the product topology) to $(x,y)$ iff $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$. This is a general fact about products of topological spaces. This property (suitably generalized to nets for non-first countable spaces) characterizes the product topology.